# Query about SOAP and HTTP fundamentals

Tags: soap, gsoap

Is a client SOAP request simply the use of HTTP POST to send a correctly formatted HTTP header followed by the correctly formatted XML SOAP content to the web service server over a TCP/IP socket connection and then waiting for and parsing the response?

Is it this 'simple' or is there more going on behind the scenes?

I ask because of difficulty using gSOAP with C++ for multiple WSDL files and am considering writing a client from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP can be used over any transport protocol like TCP, HTTP, SMTP etc with HTTP being the most popular.

SOAP over HTTP basically translates to a valid POST HTTP request with a SOAP envelope inside it, there where the form parameters would have been if we were to talk about a classic POST from the browser. The response body also contains a SOAP envelope, there where you would expect the HTML to be as response to the request from the browser.

You just have to use the proper content type for the SOAP version you are using (`text/xml` for SOAP 1.1 and `application/soap+xml` for SOAP 1.2) and maybe specify the `SOAPAction` header if needed (for SOAP 1.1), but that's about it as HTTP communication is concerned.

Then the receiver of the envelope (be it the server on a request or the client on a response) must make use of the SOAP message, but this has nothing to do with HTTP any more, HTTP just got the message there.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. So assuming that I create my SOAP request correctly and format the HTTP header correctly can I simply connect to my server via a TCP socket on port 80 and write my packet to it? Is this what HTTP actually is? Forgive my being dense on the subject - I use TCP/IP sockets all the time but I have never done anything HTTP before.

Comment: @mathematician1975: [HTTP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) is an [application layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) protocol. HTTP communication usually takes place over TCP/IP connections on the default port 80 so basically yes, if you send a request formatted according to the rules of the HTTP standard it should work. I'm not familiar with gsoap but the gsoap generated proxies should directly support HTTP making it easier on the developer (without the need to work at a lower level).